# Node.js Amazon S3 - Download fails with SignatureDoesNotMatch error

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, download, knox-amazon-s3-client

Here's the code I'm using to download a file

```
var S3_KEY = 'xxxxxx';
var S3_SECRET = 'xxxxxx';
var S3_BUCKET = 'xxxxxx';
var s3Client = require('knox').createClient({
    "key": S3_KEY,
    "secret": S3_SECRET,
    "bucket": S3_BUCKET
});

// Pull some stuff down
s3Client.get('myFile.zip').on( 'response', function(res){
    console.log( "\n" + res.statusCode );
    console.log( "\n" + res.headers + "\n" );
    res.setEncoding( 'utf8' );
    res.on('data', function( chunk ) {
        console.log( chunk );
    });
}).end();
```

I'm getting a 403 error with a SignatureDoesNotMatch code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is an issue on Knox's end. Apparently the problem has been solved, but the solution has not not pulled into the main project yet.

See this thread: https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/issues/56

My workaround was to just remove the knox library and clone this repository into my node_modules folder: https://github.com/domenic/knox.git

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the AwsSum library. It's fully-featured and actively maintained:

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum/

And there is an example of downloading from S3 in the node-awssum-scripts repo which you might find useful:

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum-scripts/blob/master/bin/amazon-s3-download.js

Give me a shout if you need any help. Disclaimer: I'm chilts, author of AwsSum. :)